# Redirecting URLs that don't contain the # in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes

With routing urls that have the hash are getting redirected (i.e. http://www.example.com/#/random).

However when I access http://www.example.com/random I do not get redirected and instead get Cannot GET /random.

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that browser has control over url of currently rendered page and can alter it in a way that won't return the same content from the server. So generally speaking you want those two to be aligned.

From the way you are asking your question I assume that you have SPA and want some client side routing and your server just renders bootstrapped SPA page that does all the work.

In this case what you want to do is force your server side to return the same SPA bootstrap page for all URLs that your SPA uses.

E.g. right now you probably have something along the lines ( say with express.js):

```
 app.get('/',rednerMyAngularBootstrap)
```

You will need to add

```
  app.get('/random', renderMyAngularBootstrap)
```

to the very end of your routing logic.

Your client side code already has client side routing and will just eat it.

Alternatively you may actually render content for `/random` right away but that's topic for another discussion.

Comment: Well /random can actually be anything after the slash

Comment: most of the server side platforms are supporting wildcard symbols etc. e.g. `app.get('/*', renderMyAngularBootstrap)` might work in your case.